# IP camera Live streaming using MpMoviePlayerController is possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, mpmovieplayercontroller, live-streaming

Can `MPMoviePlayerController` can be used for streaming from IP Camera? If not, then what `controller` would be useful for this?

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated in iOS9,

[Apple Docs,  MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/)

Here is a sample project from Apple that uses AVFoundation and live streaming,

[AVFoundationQueuePlayer-iOS: Using a Mixture of Local File Based Assets and HTTP Live Streaming Assets with AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVFoundationQueuePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html)